# Lattice structure of diamond

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

The previous question was about whether diamond can be described by an ordinary cube lattice instead of a FCC lattice. I now know that this is possible since we can still get the whole crystal in this way by translational symmetry. The question I now have is the following. It seems that if one describes a crystal using a lattice, they just take the most convenient lattice with the **lowest** number of motifs/basis vectors inside a unit cell. Is this the reason why people take diamond as a FCC lattice instead of an ordinary cube lattice whereas both are possible to describe a diamond crystal? (since the basis for ordinary cube lattice would have more elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is correct.

One place this might be useful to do is if you are simulating a material with a defect. In this case using a small unit cell is undesirable since the periodic copies of the defect will interact with one another. So you might use a 2 atom FCC cell or an 8 atom SC cell or a 32 atom BCC cell (or even larger supercells) for your simulation to reduce spurious interactions between the defect and its periodic images.

Comment: Hi Jacob, can you explain how to generate this 32 atom BCC cell? I've been scouring the internet and cannot find any material on this ...

Comment: @Bryan I'm not completely sure to be honest. Table 1 of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.71.245204) (this is just the first related thing I found) is broadly what my point was. Maybe one of the references in there is helpful for you.

Comment: Appreciate the response to an old question! I actually looked at the two papers that 'originally' showed the bcc cell, https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.67.075204 and 10.1103/PhysRevB.84.035209, but could not find any more information!